# how to hide the image/label in StoryBoard to show up when we run the app?

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a table view app which retrieves the data from the Firebase. when making the user interface in the storyboard, I am using dummy image and label to visualize my app.

but when i run the app which consists of dynamic table view, those dummy images and label also shows up before immediately replaced by the actual data that i download from the Firebase storage.

can I set those images and labels to not show up when i run the app but still available in the storyboard?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Will they eventually show actual data, or are they just dummies that you only ever want to show in Interface Builder and never in your running app?

Comment: no, just dummies to show in interface builder and never in show when I run the app :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're just dummies, you can get rid of them when your view loads, before it appears onscreen:

```
override func viewDidLoad() -> Void{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dummy.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Thanks michael, but I seperate the Tableviewcontroller file and the tableviewCell file, and the IBOutlet for those dummy images and labels are linked to the tableViewCell file, and because the class inherits UITableViewCell, so i can't acces viewDidLoad method in tableviewCell since that method only available on UITableViewController. what should I do ? thanks :)

Comment: Replace `viewDidLoad` with `awakeFromNib`

Comment: thanks michael, but maybe i didn't describe my problem well in here. if you don't mind, could you please help me here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930379/image-and-label-in-interface-builder-overlap-my-data-in-the-tableview-cell/46931935#46931935 thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to hide/show an UIView:

```
myView.isHidden = true // hide
myView.isHidden = false // show
```

I assume what you need is to hide the views in viewWillAppear and then show them when necessary.

Comment: Thanks karlo, but I seperate the Tableviewcontroller file and the tableviewCell file, and the IBOutlet for those dummy images and labels are linked to the tableViewCell file, and because the class inherits UITableViewCell, so i can't acces viewWillAppear method in tableviewCell since that method only available on UITableViewController. what should I do ? thanks :)

Comment: In that case I would use a [Notification](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-post-messages-using-notificationcenter) to let know the tableViewCell class whether or not to show the views.

Answer (score 1):

In your custom cell class, define something to hide the unwanted views:

```
func hideDummyViews() {
// do some stuff to hide what you don't want, e.g.
    myEnclosingStackView.isHidden = true
}
```

In your table view controller, in the cellForRowAt indexPath func:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

// Configure the cell ..

if yourDataSource[indexPath.row].isCompletelyLoaded { 
    // do your fancy dynamic cell layout
} else {
   // show the basic version (minus any dummy views) 
   cell.hideDummyViews()
} 

return cell
```

You can choose your preferred method for hiding the items (isHidden for each view, removing, adjusting constraints). I prefer to embed any disappearing views in a stack view and then use isHidden = true on the enclosing stack. This keeps things organized in your storyboard/XIB file and neatly recalculates constraints for the hidden stacks.

It seems that you want to show some empty (or incomplete) cells until database content arrives and then you will reload each cell as you process new entries in the datasource.  This answer will initially give you a set of cells appearing as per your storyboard/XIB, minus the hidden dummy elements. Then as items in your datasource are loaded fully, you can reload the cells.

By the way, it seems like a lot of work to carefully layout these dummy views for "visualization" and then never show them in the app.  Why not have some user-friendly place holders or progress indicators showing and then animate in the real/dynamic views as the data arrives?

Comment: thanks ozzie, but maybe i didn't describe my problem well in here. if you don't mind, could you please help me here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930379/image-and-label-in-interface-builder-overlap-my-data-in-the-tableview-cell/46931935#46931935 thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you download the Image from FireBase and does't want the dummy Image to appear
(Why dont you declare an empty ImageView and an empty Label!). Try setting an Image array in the viewController. Or you can use a struct array if you want a Image and label text together.

```
var arrImage=[UIImage]()
var arrLblTxt=[String]()
```

In view did load append your Demo Image's if required.

```
arrImage.append(UIImage("Demo"))
arrLblTxt.append("Demo")

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tbl_AssignEmployees.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as YourCell

        if arrImage[IndexPath.row] != UIImage("Demo")
        {
            cell.ImageView.Image = arrImage[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel!.text = arrLblTxt[indexPath.row]
        }
        else
        {
            cell.ImageView.Image = nil
            cell.textLabel!.text = arrLblTxt[indexPath.row]

        }


        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero

        return cell
    }
```

Then After you download your Image From FireBase,
Reset your Image array with the new Images downloaded from fireBase

Then  reload your tableView. `tableView.reloadData`

Comment: thanks jeeson, but maybe i didn't describe my problem well in here. if you don't mind, could you please help me here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930379/image-and-label-in-interface-builder-overlap-my-data-in-the-tableview-cell/46931935#46931935 thanks