# image and label in interface builder overlap my data in the TableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am a beginner in iOS development, and I want to make an instagram clone app, and I have a problem when making the news feed of the instagram clone app.

So I am using Firebase to store the image and the database. after posting the image (uploading the data to Firebase), I want to populate the table view using the uploaded data from my firebase.

But when I run the app, the dummy image and label from my storyboard overlaps the downloaded data that I put in the table view. the data that I download will eventually show after I scroll down.

Here is the gif when I run the app:

http://g.recordit.co/iGIybD9Pur.gif

There are 3 users that show in the .gif

1. username (the dummy from the storyboard)
2. JokowiRI
3. MegawatiRI

After asynchronously downloading the image from Firebase (after the loading indicator is dismissed), I expect MegawatiRI will show on the top of the table, but the dummy will show up first, but after I scroll down and back to the top, MegawatiRI will eventually shows up.

I believe that MegawatiRI is successfully downloaded, but I don't know why the dummy image seems overlaping the actual data. I don't want the dummy to show when my app running.

Here is the screenshot of the prototype cell:

[image]

And here is the simplified codes of the table view controller:

```
class NewsFeedTableViewController: UITableViewController {


    var currentUser : User!
    var media = [Media]()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        tabBarController?.delegate = self


        // to set the dynamic height of table view
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = StoryBoard.mediaCellDefaultHeight
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        // to erase the separator in the table view
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear

    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        // check wheter the user has already logged in or not

        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in

            if let user = user {

                RealTimeDatabaseReference.users(uid: user.uid).reference().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
                        self.currentUser = User(dictionary: userDict)
                    }


                })

            } else {
                // user not logged in
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: StoryBoard.showWelcomeScreen, sender: nil)
            }


        }

        tableView.reloadData()
        fetchMedia()



    }




    func fetchMedia() {

    SVProgressHUD.show()

    Media.observeNewMedia { (mediaData) in


        if !self.media.contains(mediaData) {
            self.media.insert(mediaData, at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }


        }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: StoryBoard.mediaCell, for: indexPath) as! MediaTableViewCell


        cell.currentUser = currentUser
        cell.media = media[indexPath.section]



        // to remove table view highlight style
        cell.selectionStyle = .none



        return cell
    }


    }
```

And here is the simplified code of the table view cell:

```
class MediaTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var currentUser: User!
    var media: Media! {
        didSet {

            if currentUser != nil {
                updateUI()
            }

        }
    }

    var cache = SAMCache.shared()



    func updateUI () {


        // check, if the image has already been downloaded and cached then just used the image, otherwise download from firebase storage


        self.mediaImageView.image = nil
        let cacheKey = "\(self.media.mediaUID))-postImage"

        if let image = cache?.object(forKey: cacheKey) as? UIImage {
            mediaImageView.image = image
        } else {
            media.downloadMediaImage { [weak self] (image, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                }


                if let image = image {
                    self?.mediaImageView.image = image
                    self?.cache?.setObject(image, forKey: cacheKey)

                }


            }

        }
```

So what makes the dummy image overlaps my downloaded data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

The dummy images appear because your table view controller starts rendering cells before your current user is properly set on the tableViewController.

Thus, on the first call to cellForRowAtIndexPath, you probably have a nil currentUser in your controller, which gets passed to the cell.  Hence the didSet property observer in your cell class does not call updateUI():

```
didSet {
        if currentUser != nil {
            updateUI()
        }
    }
```

Later, you reload the data and the current user has now been set, so things start to work as expected.

This line from your updateUI() should hide your dummy image. However,  updateUI is not always being called as explained above:

```
self.mediaImageView.image = nil
```

I don't really see a reason why updateUI needs the current user to be not nil.  So you could just eliminate the nil test in your didSet observer, and always call updateUI:

```
var media: Media! {
    didSet {
        updateUI()
    }
```

Alternatively, you could rearrange your table view controller to actually wait for the current user to be set before loading the data source. The login-related code in your viewWillAppear has nested completion handers to set the current user.  Those are likely executed asynchronously .. so you either have to wait for them to finish or deal with current user being nil.

```
Auth.auth etc { 
   // completes asynchronously, setting currentUser 
}
// Unless you do something to wait, the rest starts IMMEDIATELY
// currentUser is not set yet

tableView.reloadData()
fetchMedia()
```

### Other Notes

(1) I think it would be good form to reload the cell (using reloadRows) when the image downloads and has been inserted into your shared cache. You can refer to the answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789243/ios-reloading-a-uitableview-from-a-swift-class-object) to see how an asynch task initiated from a cell can contact the tableViewController using NotificationCenter or delegation.

(2) I suspect that your image download tasks currently are running in the main thread, which is probably not what you intended.  When you fix that, you *will* need to switch back to the main thread to either update the image (as you are doing now) or reload the row (as I recommend above).

Answer (score 0):

Update your UI in main thread.

```
if let image = image {
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self?.mediaImageView.image = image
    }
self?.cache?.setObject(image, forKey: cacheKey)
}
```